# Syntax error in Rails User Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax, model

I am getting this error in rails console when trying to create new User:

```
models/user.rb:32: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_DEND, expecting ')'
```

..."#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}"})if self.new_record?

Here is my Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :password
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i

validates :name,       :presence => true

validates :email,      :presence => true,
          :format                => { :with => email_regex },
          :uniqueness            => { :case_senstive => false }

validates :password,   :presence => true, 
          :confirmation          => true,
          :length                => { :within => 6..40 }

before_save :encrypt_password

def has_password?(submitted_password)
    encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
end

def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password)
    user = find_by_email(email)

    return nil if user.nil?
    return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password)
end
private
  def encrypt_password
    #generate salt for new user
    self.salt = Digest::SHA2.hexdigest("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}"}) if self.new_record?

    #encrypt password; store in encrypted_password
    self.encrypted_password = encrypt_password
end

#encrypt with salt
def encrypt(pass)
    Digest::SHA2.hexdigest("#{self.salt}--#{pass}")
end
```

end

I am not sure of the error, but console does point to the parentheses after the --#{password}"})
                         ^

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra `}` symbol right at the end of the string

Answer (score 2):

```
self.salt = Digest::SHA2.hexdigest("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}"}) if self.new_record?
```

Replace Above Line With This

```
self.salt = Digest::SHA2.hexdigest("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}") if self.new_record?
```

Answer (score 1):

change your method

```
def encrypt_password
    #generate salt for new user
    self.salt = Digest::SHA2.hexdigest("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}") if self.new_record?

    #encrypt password; store in encrypted_password
    self.encrypted_password = encrypt_password
end
```

syntax error was on

```
self.salt = Digest::SHA2.hexdigest("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}"}) if self.new_record?
```

it should be

```
self.salt = Digest::SHA2.hexdigest("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}") if self.new_record?
```

you have given a extra '}'